# ms-access vba-access Dlookup error 3464 cant get code to run

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to make sure that a value from one single record table does not excist in another table.

I have one table with a single record called Settings.
I have a second table holding Unique ID's (jobnumber) called Courier.

I am trying to make sure that the value Quotenumber in the table Settings does not excist in Jobnumber in the table Courier before moving on with the code. 
to test this I created the following.

```
Private Sub Knop0_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim Mytable As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set Mytable = db.OpenRecordset("settings")
Set Quote = Mytable!Quotenumber

If DLookup("[jobnumber]", "[courier]", "[jobnumber]= " & Quote) > 0 Then MsgBox "its in there" Else MsgBox "its not in there"


End Sub
```

when running the code i get Error 3464.
I found the problem is with "Quote" and tried to use a couple of Dim to fix this but I just cant get it to work.

Mind my experience with VBA is low and for every line of code i write i have to do extensive research. I have verry little knowledge of how DIM exactly works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[jobnumber]", "[courier]", "[jobnumber]= " & Quote & "") Then 
   MsgBox "its not in there" 
Else 
   MsgBox "its in there"
End If
```

If *Jobnumber* is text, then:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[jobnumber]", "[courier]", "[jobnumber]= '" & Quote & "'") Then
```

Comment: Oke i went with { If IsNull(DLookup("[jobnumber]", "[courier]", "[jobnumber]= " & Quote & "'")) Then
MsgBox "its not in there"
Else
MsgBox "its in there"
End If } however now i get the syntaxerror 3075 in Query expression [Jobnumber]=480010013.  now I think I am one step closer cause the number is the actuall number from the Settings table.

Comment: problem is its still not working. none of the msgboxes get triggered

Comment: Got it to work ! ofcourse with your help. here is the end result.

Comment: If DLookup("jobnumber", "courier", "jobnumber =  '" & Quote & "'") > 0 Then MsgBox "its in there" Else MsgBox "its not in there"

Comment: @Drac and what about jobnumber <= 0, You can use`DCount`instead of `DLookUp`, but your problem is jobnumber not being a number. Confuse yourself;)